# on saving cropped image it is deleting previous images

Tags: jquery, asp.net, image

I am creating image crop application using asp.net, jquery an jcrop plugin and following this tutorial:

[Image crop](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Crop-and-Upload-Image-with-Thumbnail-using-jQuery-and-HTML5-in-ASPNet.aspx)

this application working fine. but the problem is that when cropping the images more than one it replacing previous saved images. using this tutorial i can create only one croped images. but i am trying to create more than one cropped images.

i think problem is here

using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Cropped.png"), FileMode.Create))

i tried other option of create mode but nothing is working.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this overwrites because, whenever you create a new image, you are saving with the same file name in the same directory. Better you name the image with dimensions you cropped. For e.g. cropped8x8.png, cropped16x16.png etc something like this. That should solve your problem.

Comment: i am trying to create dynamic method. it is hard coded method. after cropping i want to give new name starting from 1